# How to globally register custom Liquid filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, liquid

In my Rails 5 app I'm trying to globally register [a custom Liquid filter](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#extending-liquid), but my filters aren't getting registered.

In my `root/lib` folder I save:

```
# lib/liquid_filters.rb
module DatetimeFilters
  def previous_business_day(datetime)
    Time.previous_business_day(datetime)
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(DatetimeFilters)
```

I then run it through liquid:

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
template = Liquid::Template.parse('{{ datetime | previous_business_day }}')
result   = template.render({'datetime' => Time.parse('2018-01-21 00:00:00 +0100')})
```

The expected output is:

```
'2018-01-19 00:00:00 +0100'
```

But instead the output is simply the variable, unaltered:

```
'2018-01-21 00:00:00 +0100'
```

Whatever I put into the `previous_business_day` method is ignored, which leads me to the conclusion that the filter isn't registered at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you reload rails so it can load the /lib classes? Did you try to do a `puts datetime` inside the previous_business_day to check if it's called on render, and with what input? Also, I assume you are using the business_time gem, as Time#previous_business_day is not a standard ruby nor rails method.

Comment: @FedericoG yes I've tried to add puts statements, I've tried to add random characters that would break the method, and a few other things. And yes, I have reloaded the app each time. Also, you are correct, `Time#previous_business_day` is related to the `business_time` gem, but I should maybe have chosen another example with no references to external gems.

Comment: Does it work if you assign the filter locally as in `template.render({'datetime' => Time.parse('2018-01-21 00:00:00 +0100')}, :filters => [DatetimeFilters])`? It seems to me that the /lib classes are not loading.

Comment: Hi @FedericoG. I discovered that it works when I move the module into an initializer file, and run the `register_filter ` from there. Would that be a good approach, or does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: That's great! That’s what initializers are for. Except I would define the module in lib and register it in a filters initializer. Could you post the answer?

Comment: @FedericoG OK great. I'll test it out for a few weeks and then post if it doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that when you apply the filter **previous_business_day**  it is already as a string, so try this:

```
module DatetimeFilters
  def previous_business_day(datetime)
    Time.previous_business_day(Time.parse(datetime))
  end
end
```